# Mi A1 fast charging is baffling

Tags: charging, 8.0-oreo, mi-a1

Mi A1 when it was launched (Nougat) did not have fast charging capability , though the Qualcomm chip is capable of it. It was speculated that this was done to keep the cost to fit "budget" phone model

This year it was upgraded to Oreo .Beta testing reports in December last year highlighted that fast charging has been enabled but required a Quick charger

To my utter surprise, after Oreo upgrade **miA1 gives fast charging with conventional 5V 2A chargers!** Read that again. It's true and I have tested with all chargers I have , which are mostly normal chargers . The  same charging rate I see with the only fast charger I have (Moto Turbo charger). As an example with 60 % of charge it shows 1800 mA which is typical of fast charging with any charger

It's well documented that fast charging requires a special charger which negotiates with the battery the power requirements and here you have the case of **fast charging happening with normal charger**

It's driving me crazy and I have searched Internet but couldn't find how it is possible

Question: **How is this possible?**

Fun fact : This is not the only strange thing with this device. **Unlocking boot loader doesn't wipe data**